# add Fields in zimbra mail

Tags: zimbra

I want to ask for designation and department to user in zimbra mail server. How can I add designation and department fields to zimbra  mail server user account fields ?

Comment: these fields are available for each user in Zimbra Admin console, so I don't get your question?

Comment: I just add two textboxes in Zimbra7.0 > Account > New so i can Classified Users(Employees) in Department/Designation wise.

Comment: did you read my comment? fields already exist, so are you asking for moving fields in a different place?

Comment: Please tell me Where i can find both fields and how can i add in Zimbra7.0 > Account > New

Comment: Please help me how can i add field in Zimbra7.0 > Account > New

Comment: Sorry I thought fields would exist but just checked they don't. I don't know how to add fields, try on Zimbra forunms

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an admin extension for that and save the values in the apropriate LDAP fields. Search the Zimbra wiki on how to develop an admin extension.